# Use of otherwise to indicate contrast

Tags: grammar

I am writing an essay about sports and their benefits. I wrote this sentence but I am not sure how correct it is ?

> Many games and pastimes have helped people to engaged in physical activities otherwise they would have not.

If it is correct how do I add more to the 'activities' part ?

> Many games and pastimes have helped people to engaged in physical activities which demand more energy and workout many bodyparts otherwise they would have not.

I am pretty sure the second sentence I wrote is incorrect.

Comment: "to engage in physical activities that otherwise ..." "activities which demand more energy and work more body parts *than* they would otherwise."

Comment: *Many games and pastimes have helped people to engage in physical activities **more than they would otherwise have done***. But this is writing advice, and a construction like that is way beyond what you should be thinking of using with your current level of competence. Ditch the "proofreading" aspect of the question, and ask on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for advice on how to use ***otherwise*** in simpler constructions.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers that the proofreading aspect needs to be edited out, but I think there is a question here suitable for this site if we compare the function of *otherwise* in these constructions.

Comment: @KitFox: I think you pretty much have to keep the example as presented, otherwise all you've got is a vague request for advice on how to use "otherwise". Which I contend is General Reference/Unclear for ELU, but might well be considered valid on ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two usages of 'otherwise'.

The first is the pragmatic (contrastive sentence connector) marker usage (once, and still by some, called a sentence adverb):

> Taking part in the many games and pastimes available nowadays has helped people to engage in a wealth of physical  activities.  (Otherwise they would not have done so.)

The other is the non-connector contrastive pragmatic marker / *sentence adverb:

> Many games and pastimes have helped people to engage in physical
>   activities they otherwise would not have engaged in.

*I'm at a loss with this one. I like to separate everything that doesn't obviously modify a verb from the 'adverb class', usually into the 'pragmatic marker' mix, but 'otherwise' really connects with the matrix sentence more cohesively than true pragmatic markers do. On the other hand, it sets the frame for engaging / non-engaging rather than adding information about the manner etc of engaging.

Comment: Spot on!  +1 for the second example!